# GRUB Won't Show At All- Windows 8.1 & Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, system-installation, dual-boot, 64bit

I have an HP laptop. May be irrelevant, but it's an ENVY m4.

I started out with Windows 8, then later upgraded to 8.1. Had an interest in Linux. Used a tutorial to dual boot the two OS's, since I have years of data on my Windows OS. I pretty much followed all the steps, including turning off fast start up. My only concern as far as I am knowledgeable of is the device for bootloader installation. I  believe I had "/dev/sda" or something of the sort. I believe whatever had been automatically entered on the drop-down list, along with a bunch of other numbers/words/letters; one thing in the string of entropy was "HITACHI" I think. Definitely, I hadn't used sda 1-9.
After clicking continue and going onto keyboard, user, etc., I then clicked the restart(?) button. As it is starting up again, it goes directly towards my windows 8.1 lock screen, and here I am, searching the web for problems like mine answered.

I had used http://linux.about.com/ for the tutorial. I am wondering why my laptop wouldn't show the GRUB menu, as to give me a choice between Windows 8.1 or Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit.

On a side note from all that, is the USB drive used in the tutorial still needed?

Comment: please have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported; since Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu it is pretty much the same process.